# What Star Trek novels were referenced in later TV episodes?

Tags: star-trek

Memory Alpha's ["Novels"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Novels) article has the following statement.

> *It should be noted that **certain publications written by creators of
>   Star Trek's various series are sometimes referenced in later episodes
>   of those series**. Somewhat paradoxically, the novels themselves remain
>   apocryphal in such cases, while whatever information was mentioned
>   on-screen becomes canon.*

**What events, things, or characters first introduced in a publication were later referenced in any of the TV series?** (I guess "publication" includes anything written down, like comics.)

This excludes any pre-screen treatments, such as the Star Trek Phase II documents. Since it's Wikia and unsourced it may not be entirely accurate. So "none" could be a valid answer.

Comment: Don't forget comic books.  There have been*Trek* comics since the 1970s.

Comment: Yes there are a lot of those and they would count too especially if authored by TV series creators.

Comment: Exactly.  Probably more inclusions from comics than novels, though I haven't read all the novels, by any stretch (traded my collection away in 1987).

Answer (score 5):

Hikaru Sulu received his first name in *The Entropy Effect* BY Vonda McIntyre, which was also the first mention of Nyota Uhura, although "Nyota" had apparently been agreed upon as early as the production of TOS, according to Nichele Nichols, but never came up in dialogue or the script.

Comment: Just to mention -- I seem to recall once reading in a Vonda McIntyre interview that she checked with both Gene Roddenberry (Sulu's creator) and George Takei (the original Sulu actor) beforehand, and they both said: "It's about time the poor guy had a first name!" If either of them had wanted something different, instead of Hikaru, I imagine she would have accommodated them, but neither man had his heart set on any particular first name, so they just gave her the green light to go ahead with her plan.